# Adaptive Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How can we use adaptive quadrature to approximate the following integral to $10^{-5}$?

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(6\cos4x+4\sin6x)e^x\,dx$$

Thanks

Comment: Do you want an algorithm, or want someone to point you to a software package that you can use to actually compute it? In the event of the latter, what's your favorite language? I can suggest solutions in C/C++, Matlab, and Python.

Comment: can you do this by hand, or use Matlab program? Thanks

Comment: Or the free alternative, GNU Octave: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: Have you read the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature)? Adaptive quadrature is very boring to do by hand. The [Adaptive Simpson's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Simpson%27s_method) is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Matlab, just use the `quadl` function:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html

Comment: can you put modify the matlab code for the function of interest in this question?

Comment: @JamesR - read the help page.

Answer (score 1):

[Gander and Gautschi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1022318402393) present MATLAB code for two different adaptive quadrature methods. One is based on Simpson's rule, while the other is based on the Gauss-Lobatto rule with a Kronrod extension (a modification of the usual Gaussian quadrature method). It should be straightforward to modify the code given in that paper to have it evaluate your integral.